# How can I modify a single view iOS App to navigate back to the home page from an automatically generated link to maps?

Tags: ios, navigation

I have a single view iOS UIWebView App that loads a page that have addresses in a list and have checked the option to automatically show a map to navigate to the address displayed. Only problem is, there is no way to navigate back to the list of address. The app is very simple, it is a UIWebView Container for a single website:
http://sanmateoaa.org
The app opens normally on the iPhone 4s. 
When running this website from a desktop (non-mobile) platform), I am creating a link to the address and passing it to a google maps GET using an echo statement in php (see below) and that works fine on a desktop machine (the current page changes to the google maps page and then you have to hit the back button in the browser to get back to home page (Meeting list with addresses)

echo''.$row['DAYTIME'].''.$row['MEETINGNAME'].''.''.$row['ADDRESSCITY'].''.''.$row['BLDGNAME'].'';